# How to create iterating make recipes

Tags: makefile, build-dependencies

I have a string of dependencies in my makefile.  I'd like to make a recipe to build each one.  The "For each" obviously doesn't work in Gnu Make.  Is there another option to achieve this?

```
DEPENDENCIES = dep1 dep2 dep3 ...

for each DEP in $(DEPENDENCIES)

$(DEP) : 
    $(MAKE) -C ext/$@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you don't iterate in make, you specify the dependency chain and let make handle it for you.

```
DEPENDENCIES = dep1 dep2 dep3

.PHONY: all $(DEPENDENCIES)

all: $(DEPENDENCIES)

$(DEPENDENCIES): 
    $(MAKE) -C ext/$@
```

Comment: `DEPENDENCIES = dep1 dep2 dep3

.PHONY: all $(DEPENDENCIES)

all: $(DEPENDENCIES)

$(DEPENDENCIES): 
    echo $@`

produces: 
`$make all
dep1
dep2`

Comment: @Stewbond Sorry I have no idea what your comment means.

Comment: Still getting used to this site.  Couldn't write new lines in the comments, but I tested your code, but replaced $(MAKE) with echo and everything looked great.